# Ability to click on axis (Axis Interactivity)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex3

I need to have interactive axis where user can click on it and I can return the clicked data points.

Please provide suggestions in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?:

http://demo.quietlyscheming.com/drillDown/app.html

I think its open source, check his blog

Comment: Thanks Eran.
I've seen this demo but my requirement is a bit different. In the demo, user can click on an series item and drill down into the details of that individual series. But I want to add a functionality where user can drill down for all series together by clicking on the axis. For example, suppose initillay x-axis contains Months from Jan to Dec for 2 series A and B. Now if user clicks on 'Jan' then the chart should again show both series A and B with data for Days 1 to 31 of January.